# Listener for Custom Search View in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app for data search in mysql database but i want to place the `android searchView` in activity part and not in action bar.

In my `main.xml` file I define the search view code and search view appears, but how can I listen for the events of that search view in java code?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setOnQueryTextListener on your searchView. When user ends their input in your searchView and press "Done" or "Enter" depending on what imeType you set , then you have to fire the search , that means you have to run your fetch request to get the result data and show it to user.

Edit: Sample code

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (query.length() != 0) {
            System.out.println("--->" + query);
            // handle search here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: but i want search on particular character which enter by user.